# Selecting keys in Graph Editor from different channels at same time and value?

Tags: selection-tools, graph-editor

Is it possible in the Graph Editor to select keyframes from different channels that are stacked on the same time and value? I have tried box select, various shift-select combinations, the k and alt-k hotkeys for column select etc. without success. It doesn't matter if I have all my channels selected, I can only select a single key. This is really a problem for my workflow-- but perhaps I am missing something obvious.

On the left I've made all 3 channels active-- on the right after box select only one channel and key have been selected.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I finally realized that I was clicking again on the key to move it-- which deselected the other channels. Need to click-drag away from the keys to move them together.

BUT... when multiple keys are selected the numeric boxes disappear from the properties panel! Is there a way to assign a single numeric value to multiple keys?

Comment: Ask new question as a new question please. Moving keys is best to do with G tool (same as in viewport)

Comment: After selecting all keys press G, then Y or X depending on which direction you want to move keys and then number

Comment: Thank you--I also have discovered that you can snap the keys to the cursor time/value entered numerically.